# Flutter doesn't connect to Firebase [NoSuchMethodError], The method 'set...' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter

How to connect my flutter app in android studio with my database in firebase? Running the code in the console works fine on the mobile SDK. But if you write one item into the add item field following error occurs:

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'setZigarren' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: setZigarren("h", false)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _humidorState.addZigarren (package:zigarre/humidor.dart:18:14)
#2      _AddItemDialogState.save (package:zigarre/add_item_dialog.dart:19:25)
#3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:993:19)
#4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1111:38)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#874b7
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(193.8, 290.5)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(41.4, 6.9)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
====================================================================================================
```

Code: Method setZigarren

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {

  final String userID;
  DatabaseService(this.userID);

  final CollectionReference userZigarren = Firestore.instance.collection('userZigarren');

  Future setZigarren(String key, bool value) async {
    return await userZigarren.document(userID).setData(
        {key: value}, merge: true);
  }

  Future deleteZigarren(String key) async {
    return await userZigarren.document(userID).updateData({
      key: FieldValue.delete(),
    });
  }

  Future checkIfUserExists() async {
    if ((await userZigarren.document(userID).get()).exists) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the part of code which use "setZigarren" method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. Just had to restart android studio. It is often too simple.